# "Type of import (".../charjs/types/indexsm" has no construct signatures issue on Vue3 and ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to use ChartJS (NOT vue-chartjs), it was working just fine, and then this error came up. Here's my code:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const optionsSubMenu = computed(() => {
      return [
        {
          to: `/expenses/history`,
          title: 'History'
        },
        {
          title: 'Payables'
        },
        {
          title: 'Receivers'
        }
      ]
    })

    onMounted(() => {
      const ctx = document.getElementById('expenses-chart') as HTMLCanvasElement
      const canv = ctx.getContext('2')
      THE ERROR POINTS TO THIS "new Chart"
      new Chart(canv, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Category 1',
              type: 'bar',
              data: [5008, 23873, 32122, 16322, 8033, 43381, 12562],
              backgroundColor: '#b7b7b7',
              borderColor: '#b7b7b7',
              barThickness: 30
            }
          ]
        }
        }
      })
    })
```

While my devtools shows this:

```
**SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/chart_js.js?v=b552445d' does not provide an export named 'default'**
```

So...anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: `defineComponent` is nothing, so you probably want to load that in. Or make that `export default **function** defineComponent(...) { ... }` if the intent was to export a function? Not entirely clear because you didn't explain things in terms of what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thank you! I was in a hurry and I forgot to add more information. Turns out I had to import Chart.js on another file and make it globally available, then it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Chart.js v3 is treeshakable so the way you use it has changed, see documentation on how to use all the ways (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/integration.html#bundlers-webpack-rollup-etc),

Most easy way like you are used to you have to make your import statement like this: `import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';`

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! I changed to /auto on another project and it worked just fine. The project I was having issues with just didn't want to work with any import, then I decided to make it globally available and it worked and I also added the /auto. Thank you sooo much!